# Pass Custom object from servlet to ajax and display in jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Is that any method to pass custome object from servlet to ajax and display in jsp page?
When accept inventory id from jsp page, it pass to servlet and get the inventory object based on the id. After that, i want to pass the inventory object back to the ajax and display in jsp page

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborate on your question? Show us some code, some thing that is working and then tell us exactly what you want to do more. Also it would be good if you can read the FAQ about how to ask questions on SO

Comment: How do you do ajax call to servlet? can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer as you did not describe your problem in deep.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {

  // Method to handle GET method request.
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      //declaring custom object
      Person person = new Person("FirstName","LastName");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.print(person);
  }
  // Method to handle POST method request.
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
     doGet(request, response);
  }
}
```